# How to deploy Resources to Azure without using personal MSDN login (not web apps)

Tags: azure, credentials, continuous-deployment

I am working on a powershell script the deploys azure templates that create all manner of resources on azure (resource groups, VMs, network configurations, peerings, runbooks etc)  Since I started, I've been mainly running them from my desktop, logging in using my msdn username and password, and from there on the script would have the access it needs.

I've explored Service Principals but I believe those are mainly for deploying Azure Web Apps.

The goal is move my scripts to the Atlassian Bamboo Deployment server, where they can be run by anyone with access to the system.  It also greatly helps with continuous integration.

I've been googling but alas, I do not know the terms / correct questions to ask.